# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java

I'm a novice Java programmer. I dont know what is wrong with the main method, it keeps pointing me to this line

```
    int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

this is my code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    assert args.length == 1;
    int x = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    while (x != 1) {
        x = nextInt(x);
        System.out.print(" " + x);
    }
}

public static int nextInt(int x) {
    if (x % 2 == 0) {
        return x / 2;
    } else
        return 3 * x + 1;
}
```

Comment: When asking about an error, please post the error message.  There could be a few things going on, and the actual error is more helpful than just the line number.

Comment: @hexafraction Java doesn't do shell-style name arguments. args[0] is the first argument, not the name of the class.

Comment: Java does not behave this way (First argument is program name). Does the assert evalutate to true?

Comment: Regarding the 'compiler-errors' tag on this, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is not a compilation error; it's a runtime error.

Comment: If not then you must define arguments to your program. Otherwise the array "args" will be size 0 and 0 will be out of bounds.

Comment: You're invoking the `java` command without any parameters (other than the class name).  Do `java MyClass 12345` and it'll run past that line.

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to assume that you are using a number in the first argument of your program call.

You are using asserts, verify that assertions are activated. Execute your code with the VM argument: `-ea`.

Comment: This is good advice, but if the tag is correct, he's having compiler problems, not runtime.

Comment: @chrylis do you see any compiler problems in the line with trouble? it is more likely that: 1) he's doesn't have a parseable number as first argument, or 2) the doesn't even have any arguments in the command line

Comment: No, it looks perfectly correct, but it is tagged `compiler-errors`.

Answer (score 1):

Simply said, in Java the `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` means there is no array element in the specified index of your array.

So make sure you input at least 1 argument when running your java app from the command prompt. In your case, it should be parsable to an Integer.

For Example:

```
java {class_name_with_main_methof} {argument_1} {argument_2}
```

Comment: Exactly one, because of the `assert` condition.

Comment: @chrylis asserts are not always on

Comment: @RiaD No, they're not, but that's what he's using for error-checking in this example. It's not the best choice, but that's another issue.